# WaitCursor while operating

Tags: vb.net

I have the following problem:

The serialization takes some time and I want to change the Cursor to WaitCursor for that time, so the user knows the program is still working and not crashed.
But while serializing, the program seems the change the Cursor to Default automatically. So in this case I don't see the WaitCursor at all. If I delete `Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default` the WaitCursor is just displayed after the new file is saved.

Is there a way to fix that and display the WaitCursor while the program is operating?

```
If Dialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
            Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.Open(Dialog.FileName, IO.FileMode.Open)
            Dim serializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(ESL.SCL.SCL))
            Dim SCL As ESL.SCL.SCL
            SCL = serializer.Deserialize(fs)
            fs.Close()
            Dim Exporter As WMSExporter = New WMSExporter
            Dim SCLWMS As ESL.SCL.SCL = Exporter.Export(SCL)
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default

            Dim CloseDialog As New SaveFileDialog
            CloseDialog.Filter = "ssd|*.ssd|scd|*.scd|icd|*.icd|iid|*iid"
            If CloseDialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

                fs = System.IO.File.Create(CloseDialog.FileName)
                SCLWMS.revision = "A"
                serializer.Serialize(fs, SCLWMS)

                fs.Close()
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Datei wurde erfolgreich gespeichert", "OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            Else
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Datei wurde NICHT erfolgreich gespeichert", "OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            End If
    End If
```

I also tried to work asynchronously:

```
      If Dialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf load_scl)
        thread.Start(Dialog.FileName)


        thread.Join()
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
      End if

Private Sub load_scl(filename As String)
    Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.Open(filename, IO.FileMode.Open)
    Dim serializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(ESL.SCL.SCL))
    Dim SCL As ESL.SCL.SCL
    SCL = serializer.Deserialize(fs)
    fs.Close()
    Dim Exporter As WMSExporter = New WMSExporter
    Dim SCLWMS As ESL.SCL.SCL = Exporter.Export(SCL)
    'Me.UseWaitCursor = False
    Dim CloseDialog As New SaveFileDialog
    CloseDialog.Filter = "ssd|*.ssd|scd|*.scd|icd|*.icd|iid|*iid"
    If CloseDialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        fs = System.IO.File.Create(CloseDialog.FileName)
        SCLWMS.revision = "A"
        serializer.Serialize(fs, SCLWMS)

        fs.Close()
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Datei wurde erfolgreich gespeichert", "OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    Else
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Datei wurde NICHT erfolgreich gespeichert", "OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End If
End Sub
```

The Problem here is, that I get a ThreadStateException. 
So I thought there might be an easier solution.

Comment: The issue is presumably the fact that you're doing all the work on the UI thread, so there's no way to update the UI during that.  A quick and dirty workaround may be to call `Refresh` on the form after setting the `Cursor` but a better solution would be to perform the work asynchronously.

Comment: By calling `thread.Join()` you make it wait for `thread` to complete before the rest of the code is executed, thus you make it synchronous and lose the whole concept of having another thread. Remove `thread.Join()` and you should be good to go.

Comment: But how does the program know when the other thread is finished and the Cursor can be set back to default?